# Remove lines from color and fill legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I have a plot with three different legends: one for `linetype`, one for `color`, and one for `fill`. In the `color` and `fill` legends there are also some lines which I wish to remove, but how?

Here is some example code:

```
# some data
hline_df <- data.frame(name = c('a', 'b'), y = c(1, 2))
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(0.5, 1.5), con = c('a', 'b'), col = c('d', 'e'))

# the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = con)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(color = col)) +
  geom_hline(data = hline_df, aes(yintercept = y, linetype = name),
             color = 'red', show_guide = TRUE)
```

[image]

I get the "name" guide for both red lines, that is fine.
The "col" guide has red lines crossing the dots, I want to remove them!
The "con" guide also has red lines which should be removed.

I could modify parts of the legend with

```
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)),
       color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

This removes the colour, but the lines are still there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm, rearranging to `ggplot(df, aes(x,y,fill=con)) + 
  geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name), color='red',show_guide=TRUE) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name), color='red',show_guide=F)` seems to work for `con` but the red line is still in `col`. And to be honest, I don't understand, why it is working :-)

Comment: Ahhh, I tried to set `linetype=NULL`  and this didn't worked as expected... Also the trick with plotting the hline two times, on in the back and one in the front is great! Would you like to post an answer, so I can mark it as fixed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You may set `linetype = 0` or `"blank"` (on different `linetype`s [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/aes_linetype_size_shape.html)) for the `fill`and `color` `guide`s in your `override.aes` call.

Also note that I moved the `fill` `aes` from the 'top level' in `ggplot` to `geom_bar`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = con), stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(color = col)) +
  geom_hline(data = hline_df, aes(yintercept = y, linetype = name), color = 'red', show_guide = TRUE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is even a bit cleaner and explains the problem... It just sets the aes linetype to 0 for the fill and the color legend... Great!

Comment: Excellent answer. I was working on a solution with extracting the several legends and then trying to put them together into one plot. However, this is a much better and much more elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by user20650

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name), color='red',show_guide=TRUE) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=col), size=5) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=con), stat='identity') + 
  geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name), color='red',show_guide=F) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

So the first geom_hline creates the legend but the line is behind the bars...
the second call brings the line in front of the bars but does not print a legend (great idea).
The las guide is overwriting the aesthetics line type with 0... In this way it removes the line from the legends... I tried with `NULL` but this didn't worked before...

Thanks again.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,fill=con)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(color=col)) +
  geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name),color='red',show_guide=FALSE) +
  guides(linetype=FALSE,color=FALSE)
```

gives me this plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jaap, but I want to have the all guides... Just want to remove the red line from the `con` and the `col` guide...

Comment: So, basically `ggplot(df, aes(x,y,fill=con)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(color=col)) + geom_hline(data=hline_df,aes(yintercept=y,linetype=name),color='red',show_guide=FALSE)` is the expected result for `con` and `col`, but I need a guide for the red lines as well...